# How to make placeholder for search input in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I've override default wordpress search form by creating my own search form (found this code in google). here it is:

```
<form method="get" class="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
<div>
<input class="text" type="text" value="<?php if(trim(wp_specialchars($s,1))!='') echo trim(wp_specialchars($s,1));else echo ' ';?>" name="s" id="s" />
</div>
</form>
```

I tried to add a place holder for this & change my code for input line to this:

```
<input class="text" type="text" value="<?php if(trim(wp_specialchars($s,1))!='') echo trim(wp_specialchars($s,1));else echo ' ';?>" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search Here" />
```

but it is not working for me. please help someone.

Comment: remove `else echo ' '` from the input value...

Comment: @Dinesh the OP doesn't need to remove `else echo ' '`. They should change it to `else echo ''`, *without* the single space between the quote marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply use the placeholder attribute like so:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search the site"/>
```

If you put a value, the value will overwrite your placeholder. Try to delete the value from your input and it should work

Comment: @AohorArsalan in the code you provided, there was a single space that was being echoed with `else echo ' '` which would count as a value and override your placeholder value. Using `value=""` will not override the placeholder value.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `placeholder` on your input tag like

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search the site"/>
```

Comment: Why should one not use the `value` attribute when using the `placeholder` attribute for an `input` tag? I think what you mean is, if the `value` attribute is used and has a value set, it will override the value of the `placeholder` attribute. Which if perfectly fine.

Comment: @hungerstar yeah if we use value and placeholder together it will override the value of placeholder..:)

Comment: My point is, you can use them together. Your answer seems to suggest you shouldn't use them together. Which would be incorrect.

Comment: @hungerstar now check ..:)